# Javascript replace string in URL

Tags: javascript, regex, yii, datepicker

I thought this was trivial but couldn't solve it out :(

I want to change a param passed in mu url with javascript.

```
var url = "http://example.com/categoryname/5/%23date/archive";
url = url.replace(/%23date/g, newDateValue);
```

I have searched all more than hours on the internet, but still not fixed. please help!

**update**

here is the complete code in Yii

```
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
        'name' => 'inline_datepicker',
        'flat' => true,
        'language' => Yii::app()->language,
        'value' => strtotime($date),
        'themeUrl' => Yii::app()->baseUrl,
        'theme' => 'themes/haber',
        'cssFile' => '/lib/styles/datepicker.css',
        'options' => array(
            'dateFormat' => 'dd-mm-yy',
            'showButtonPanel' => 'true',
            'onSelect' => 'js:function(selectedDate){var url = \'' . Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("category/archive", array("id" => $_GET['id'], "name" => $_GET['name'], "date" => "#date")) . '\';  url.replace(/#date/g, selectedDate); alert(url);}',
            'showAnim' => 'slide',//$(location).attr("href", url);
        ))
    );
```

Comment: Your code seems to be [working just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/nBD2N/)... or am I missing something?

Comment: Works for me. Please provide a **complete** example of the problem. http://i.stack.imgur.com/88cBR.png

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/M64se/ Working

Comment: I see, but I can not understand way it does not work by me :((

Comment: Is newDateValue declared?

Comment: @Xiabili - what is your desired output? What are you getting instead?

Comment: What does not work...

Comment: First of all, you didn't specify what's not working and what is the result you're getting. Second, it's probably `newDateValue` that's making the problem.

Comment: your yii code is missing `url = url.replace(/date/g, selectedDate);`. this is weird since your other code has it.

Comment: @LoganMurphy thanks! :) I spent all more than one hour to fix that!!

Comment: why downvote?? there are some lol around thinks that he never make mistake!